# Swing - After setVisible(false) white space remains

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have an outer JPanel that holds a list of inner panels in it, and my Layout is *GridLayout*

Under certain conditions, I want to render invisible some of my inner panels. The problem is, after I do `setVisible(false)` on some of my inner panels, they do disappear but their previous occupied space still remains and does not wipe out, therefore it creates white spaces.

How to remove those white spaces and make all visible inner panels to sort one after another without any white space in between them?

```
outerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
outerPanel.add(pnl1);
outerPanel.add(pnl2);
outerPanel.add(pnl3);
outerPanel.add(pnl4);

private void invisibleSome(){
 Component[] cmpts = outerPanel.getComponents();
   for(int i = 0; i< cmpts.length; i++){
       //this make some components invisible 
       //but their white space still remains
       cmpts[i].setVisible(i%2 == 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` after removing components

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `GridLayout` will not `revalidate()` properly after the component gets visible. I thought it will work too but it does not.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no I don't forget those, try GridLayout and you will see what will happen

Comment: what's wrong with my question that I am getting negative points ? I think it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **BoxLayout** and my problem solved :

```
outerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the visibility of the panels will not remove them from your grid.

You should try to remove them from the grid using this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#removeLayoutComponent(java.awt.Component)

Afterwards you maybe have to set the prefered size of the cell so it becomes smaller and you don't have a blank space in between.
Another way would be to update all of the panels below to move up one cell.

Using the second method it would probably be easier to keep the ones you want to be displayed in a list, remove the one you want from the list, remove all panels from the layout and build a completely new layout from the list of panels you want to display.

Comment: I knew this but, I don't want to remove them. Is there any way to do it without removing it ?

Comment: I'm not quite shure if this will work but  you could try to set the maximum height of the cell to 0 or 1. So it will not really be removed but will be displayed on only 1 pixel. If this doesn't work using GridLayout maybe try MigLayout, which is more powerfull (and a default layout in eclipse and window-builder)

Comment: I try the MigLayout

Comment: Thanks man, I used BoxLayout and my problem solved. By the way, I didn't give you negative point, I don't know who did it ... They gave me 2 negative points also